# New SSD and different OS

Tags: windows, backup, restore

Last summer, my Lenovo AIO suddenly stopped working; more specifically, I was performing maintenance on it and the next restart gave an error 1962: No Operating System found. Fortunately, this is a well known error among Lenovo brand machines. Unfortunately, there is really no clear answer or consensus on what the solution is. For some people, changing a setting in bios fixed it, for others it was the SATA cable, etc.  I took my hard drive out and attempted to see if it would boot up externally with another company, or at least be recognized. No such luck. I decided to just go ahead and replace the hard drive a 1 TB SSD and ended up with a clean install of Windows 10 (my now-dead HDD was running Windows 8.1). Ironically, the maintenance I had been performing right before it died was a full back up of my system to my Acronis Cloud account. I also have a couple of external hard drive‘s that have the back up and/or a system image of my now defunct HDD. Although they’re not recent the most recent files, really all I’m wanting is pretty much just save the many photos that I have (like most people). My question is, can I attempt to somehow restore that back up to a computer that is now running Win 10? 
Or is there someway that I can just get the photo files and possibly some other files I may want to keep? I know for a fact I have a system image copied to an external hard drive, it might be a year old but it would be helpful. How would I go about doing this, if it’s possible?  Thanks!

Comment: Windows' "System Image Backups' just use big VHD disk image files, which I expected to be able to use with Windows 10's "Attach VHD" feature in Disk Management to take a look around inside, but when I tested this on an actual VHD file from a backup I got a generic error message about the operation only supporting uncompressed unencrypted non-sparse files, so my particular backup must not qualify for one of those; ymmv. I also have 7-zip installed, and 7-zip was able to open and extract files from the backup's VHD files without issue.

Comment: Well, i’m just a little nervous to mess with it much because I’m worried that I may mess up the system/computer that I’m using to recover the files. I’m really A little excited that I have a brand new one terabyte ssd (got it for a steal at Christmas time) and a clean install of Windows 10 (I tried every which way to get my windows 8.1 to upgrade and it absolutely refused to do it so I gave up trying to switch to 10 ). The last time I looked at ssd’s, the only one that I could  afford was a very small 250 GB  I kind of feel like I have an almost brand new computer now.